# Is there a way to put several SQL to diffrente servers inside the same transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, distributed-transactions, cross-server

In my system we do action, and for reporting sake we log that action on another server (star schema if it interests).
Obviously I need the action updates/inserts be in the same transaction as the logging.
So, is there a way to include two different sqls to two different servers in the same transaction?
Right now I manage that in the code level (php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible with MySQL alone.  While MySQL does have a [Federated Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html) (ie: remote access to other MySQL servers) it doesn't support transactions.  That means you can't coordinate a multi-server transaction directly through MySQL.  MySQL does support [XA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA) [for InnoDB tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xa.html), so you can use an external transaction manager with MySQL, but PHP doesn't have any support for XA.  Generally this is considered an Enterprise-level feature, and you'd implement using [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API) or [C#/.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684146%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [distributed transaction coordinator.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759136(WS.10).aspx)

[Configuring DTC.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301600)

Comment: I don't think that MS-DTC supports MySQL, and PHP probably doesn't have any links to MS-DTC either.

Answer (score 0):

Complicated way is:

1. create same table on same server.
2. Make this server master
3. Set replica an this table

if you want that log table be not very big you can do:

4. first table name set _tmp
5. create on slave log_tmp trigger on insert and update to copy data to log table
6. after some time to delete from log_tmp in master some data.